# Ressource loading delay when using HTML5 cache manifest and Ember / JQuery

Tags: jquery, ember.js, loading, html5-appcache, low-latency

### tl;dr:

**How can I improve the static content loading times further, and remove the 300 or so ms where the browser seems to do nothing [in that picture](http://fr.tinypic.com/r/28aja0g/8)?**

### Some background

I am working on increasing the performance of a monitoring webapp.
This app is integrated to other websites as an iframe (yea...). Parent sites will call the webapp again on most page changes, so the "webapp widget" is very often loaded from scratch during navigation.

*I have no control over this design*, and can only ensure that a call to the webapp will return the expected content as fast as possible.

Data is manipulated in the webapp with Ember.js, with a store that depreciates after a while, and will call again (though the RESTful adapter) for an update. The JSON coming from this REST endpoint call is the only dynamic resource. It's pretty much as good as it can be: cache-control on client side, server-side optimizations, etc.

To limit the loading times due to frequent calls to the static resources, I used HTML5's cache. As you can see [in that screenshot](http://fr.tinypic.com/r/28aja0g/8), it's quite efficient. All the data except from the dynamic JSON is loaded from cache, at lightning speeds. However, what I don't get is the delay between the 200 ms and 380 ms mark. What is the browser doing? Is executing the Ember.js code that long? (It's very simple, really.) Also, why no parallel loading of resources between the 380 and 450 ms marks? Even the two hbs templates are loaded sequentially.)

- **Are these really the best times I can expect?**
- **If not, where to look for further optimisations?**

I will provide code as needed, but I'm not even sure my Ember app is at fault here.

Comment: First check if it has to do with ember related resources or with your ember code. For example remove the ember related files with your app and try, then remove only your app code. Regardless of the results, that may assist some suggestions are to use minified files, combine them to minimize requests (although these are cached), precompile templates and add them as js files.

Comment: bundle and minification is the way to go for sure.  Using html5 cache isn't necessary either if your browser is sending proper headers back.  Decrease the pipeline for serving static content server side (often this is moved off to a third party, cloudflare etc).